# Cross-compiling code (arm32) for yocto image (aarch64)

Tags: compilation, arm, cross-compiling, yocto

I need to a code written for arm32 to be compiled and run on a aarch64 based yocto image. My host system is x86 and thus I am able to compile x86 code for the image.
Is there a way I can compile this arm32 code on either my host or target device?
I am aware that meta-toolchain may be of help here but I am not sure how to use this tool in this particular case.

I tried using aarch64-linux-gnu and arm-linux-gnueabi toolchains on the x86 host systems. I was expecting the arm-linux-gnu toolchain to compile the arm32 code.

Also, I tried using -m32 option on my target aarch64 system for compiling, but the option is only available on x86 systems.

Comment: "I was expecting the arm-linux-gnu toolchain to compile the arm32 code."  Yes, it should, what happened when you tried?  Do you have the appropriate arm32 libraries installed as well?

Comment: The libraries used by the code includes systemd libraries, but I am unsuccessful installing them. So, If possible I would like to install the toolchain on the target system itself.

Comment: Also If I am able to build a binary using this toolchain, I will not be able to run it on my target system (aarch64).